# How to get start date of child time frame within parent time frame

Tags: php

I know exact date of the beginning of the month but I need to know when first week of this month begins and this week can start outside of this month.

I can do something like - find weekday when "MONTH" starts and subtract number of days to the beginning of the "WEEK" :

```
$weekday = d('w', $monthStartTimeStamp);
$weekStart = $monthStartTimeStamp - strtotime('1 day', 0) * (7 - $weekday);
```

**Question :**

Is there some way to make this calculation more generic for time frames that I do not know in advance?

**Possible use cases :**

1. Given some "DATETIME" get datetime of the first "YEAR"
2. Given some "DATETIME" get datetime of the first "MONTH"
3. Given some "DATETIME" get datetime of the first "WEEK"
4. Given some "DATETIME" get datetime of the first "DAY"
5. Given some "DATETIME" get datetime of the first "HOUR"
6. Given some "DATETIME" get datetime of the first "MINUTE"

For date time 2016-01-10 10:30 results would be :

1. YEAR : 2016-01-01 00:00
2. MONTH : 2016-01-01 00:00
3. WEEK : 2016-01-04 00:00
4. DAY : 2016-01-10 00:00
5. HOUR : 2016-01-10 10:00
6. MINUTE : 2016-01-10 10:30

P. S. most of the questions here specify what exactly time frame is required, e.g. "How to get beginning of the year", they do not answer how to do this for ant time frame.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to do it "manually" for each possible case as they differ in so many ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea in pseudocode:

- You already have the hardest case for the week
- For the rest: Convert the date to a format like: YYYYMMDDHHmm, then depending on the $interval just change the right X characters to 0:

`

```
$int2char = array(
    'YEAR' => 8,
    'MONTH' => 6,
    'DAY' => 4,
    'HOUR' => 2,
    'MINUTE' => 0
);

$interval = 'MONTH';
$str = date("YmdHi", $timestamp);
$zeros = $int2char[$interval];
$d = substring($str, 0, 12-$zeros) . substring("00000000", 0, $zeros);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $d);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

`